# How to convert 8 17-bit integers into 17 8-bit integers efficiently

Tags: c++, integer

Okay, I have the following problem: I have a set of 8 (unsigned) numbers that are all 17bit (a.k.a. none of them are any bigger than 131071). Since 17bit numbers are annoying work work with (keeping them in a 32-bit int is a waste of space), I would like to turn these into 17 8-bit numbers, like so:

If I have these 8 17-bit integers:

```
[25409, 23885, 24721, 23159, 25409, 23885, 24721, 23159]
```

I would turn them into a base 2 representationL

```
["00110001101000001", "00101110101001101", "00110000010010001", "00101101001110111", "00110001101000001", "00101110101001101", "00110000010010001", "00101101001110111"]
```

Then join that into one big string:

```
"0011000110100000100101110101001101001100000100100010010110100111011100110001101000001001011101010011010011000001001000100101101001110111"
```

Then split that into 17 strings, each with 8 chars:

```
["00110001", "10100000", "10010111", "01010011", "01001100", "00010010", "00100101", "10100111", "01110011", "00011010", "00001001", "01110101", "00110100", "11000001", "00100010", "01011010", "01110111"]
```

And, finally, convert the binary representations back into integers

```
[49, 160, 151, 83, 76, 18, 37, 167, 115, 26, 9, 117, 52, 193, 34, 90, 119]
```

This method works, but it's not very efficient, I am looking for something more efficient than this, preferrably coded in C++, since that's the language I am working with. I just can't think of any way to do this more efficient, and 17-bit numbers aren't exactly easy to work with (16-bit numbers would be much nicer to work with).

Thanks in advance, xfbs

Comment: What platform are you working on that you're worried about wasting space by storing these in 32-bit integers?

Comment: @Praetorian: presumably any platform that has less memory available than double the size of the data.

Comment: @Steve Jessop Well, it's not exactly double, just 88% more space :-) But seriously, if those numbers are expected as 17-bit integers by some other part of the program, instead of an array of bytes squeezed next to each other, the OP would have re-convert these to the 17-bit representation. It's arguable whether he's saving memory with all the format massaging code.

Comment: What criteria are you worried about efficiency?  speed? memory? on disk serialization?  I'm curious about the platform question too, this seems like you're over-thinking if it is nothing special.

Comment: In fact, I'm not so much worried about wasting space, another reason is that I can export 8bit integers easily: they happen to have just the right size to convert them into chars, then I can export the whole thing as a string.

Answer (score 11):

Store the lowest 16 bits of each number as-is (i.e. in two bytes). This leaves the most significant bit of each number. Since there are eight such numbers, simply combine the eight bits into one extra byte.

This will require exactly the same amount of memory as your method, but will involve a lot less bit twiddling.

P.S. Regardless of the storage method, you should be using bit-manipulation operators (`<<`, `>>`, `&`, `|` and so on) to do the job; there should not be any intermediate string-based representations involved.

Comment: I have thought about this, but then I wouldn't get the same output as from the method I'm currently using, and I don't really want to change it due to backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at `std::bitset<N>`. May be you can stuff them into that?

Comment: well, i could also stuff them into a vector<bool>, but how would that be useful? does bitset have facilities to export the data in a different form (8bit int)?

Comment: the point of this answer is to completely redesign your program so it uses `std::bitset` always instead of doing this repacking at all.

Comment: @xfbs, you didn't provide us with the details, so I can't answer your question.

Comment: @unkulunkulu well, what I mean is that I'm looking for 17 8-bit ints, so the output would be numbers. However, I can use bitset in any case since it's probably better (more efficient, less memory used) to use that than to use a string.

Answer (score 2):

Efficiently? Then don't use string conversions, bitfields, etc. Manage to do shifts yourself to achieve that. (Note that the arrays must be `unsigned` so that we don't encounter problems when shifting).

```
uint32 A[8]; //Your input, unsigned int
ubyte B[17]; //Output, unsigned byte
B[0] = (ubyte)A[0];
B[1] = (ubyte)(A[0] >> 8);
B[2] = (ubyte)A[1];
B[3] = (ubyte)(A[1] >> 8);
.
:
```

And for the last one, we do what ajx said. We take the most significant digit of each number (shifting them 16 bits to the right leaves the 17th digit) and fill the bits of our output by shifting each of the most significant digits from 0 to 7 to the left:

```
B[16] = (A[0] >> 16)  | ((A[1] >> 16) << 1) | ((A[2] >> 16) << 2) | ((A[3] >> 16) << 3) | ... | ((A[7] >> 16) << 7);
```

Well, "efficient" was this. Other easier methods exist, too.

Comment: thanks! i never thought of using shift operations... this sounds like it'd be way faster than having to temporarily convert the numbers to strings, and it is probably faster, too, since shifts take little CPU cycles :D thank you, i'll try this

Comment: Hm, thinking about it, there might be a little flaw: Do I have to worry about endianess?

Comment: endianness is about how integers bigger than 1 byte are stored into memory; but you have not to worry about since you just read the "number" from the source (no matter how they are in memory, `0xff00 >> 8` will give the same result on a big endian or little endian machine) and write out bytes consistently (even if you would have output 16-bit words, the story would have been the same)

Answer (score 1):

Though you say they are 17-bit numbers, they must be stored into an array of 32bit integers, where only the less significant 17 bits are used. You can extract from the first directly two bytes (`dst[0] = src[0] >> 9` is the first, `dst[1] = (src[0] >> 1) & 0xff` the second); then you "push" the first bit as the 18th bit of the second, so that

```
  dst[2] = (src[0] & 1) << 7 | src[1] >> 10;
  dst[3] = (src[1] >> 2) & 0xff;
```

if you generalize it, you will see that this "formula" may be applied

```
   dst[2*i] = src[i] >> (9+i) | (src[i-1] & BITS(i)) << (8-i);
   dst[2*i + 1] = (src[i] >> (i+1)) & 0xff;
```

and for the last one: `dst[16] = src[7] & 0xff;`.

The whole code could look like

```
  dst[0] = src[0] >> 9;
  dst[1] = (src[0] >> 1) & 0xff;

  for(i = 1; i < 8; i++)
  {
    dst[2*i] = src[i] >> (9+i) | (src[i-1] & BITS(i)) << (8-i);
    dst[2*i + 1] = (src[i] >> (i+1)) & 0xff;
  }
  dst[16] = src[7] & 0xff;
```

Likely analysing better the loops, optimizations can be done so that we don't need to treat in a special manner the cases on the boundaries. The BITS macro create a mask of N bits set to 1 (least significant bits). Something like (to be checked for a better way, if any)

```
#define BITS(I) (~((~0)<<(I)))
```

**ADD**

Here I supposed src is e.g. `int32_t` and dst `int8_t` or alike.

Comment: this works only if you have 8 "17-bits" integers, and `int` is bigger than 16-bit; because of masking and bit range we are considering, you should not be worried about `>>` or `<<` being arithmetic or logical shifts (i hope not to be wrong!).

Answer (score 0):

This is in C, so you can use `vector` instead.

```
#define srcLength 8
#define destLength 17
int src[srcLength] = { 25409, 23885, 24721, 23159, 25409, 23885, 24721, 23159 };
unsigned char dest[destLength] = { 0 };

int srcElement = 0;
int bits = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

do {
    while( bits >= srcLength ) {
        dest[i++] = srcElement >> (bits - srcLength);
        srcElement = srcElement & ((1 << bits) - 1);
        bits -= srcLength;
    }

    if( j < srcLength ) {
        srcElement <<= destLength;
        bits += destLength;
        srcElement |= src[j++];
    }
} while (bits > 0);
```

Disclaimer: if you literally have **seventeen** integers (and not 100000 groups by 17), you should forget these optimizations as long as your program doesn't run veeery slowly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go about it this way.  I don't want to deal with weird types when I'm doing my processing.  Maybe I need to store them in some funky formatting due to legacy problems though.  The values that are hard-coded should probably be based off of the 17 value, just didn't bother.

```
struct int_block {
    static const uint32 w = 17;
    static const uint32 m = 131071;
    int_block() : data(151, 0) {} // w * 8 + (sizeof(uint32) - w)
    uint32 get(size_t i) const {
        uint32 retval = *reinterpret_cast<const uint32 *>( &data[i*w] );
        retval &= m;
        return retval;
    }
    void set(size_t i, uint32 val) {
        uint32 prev = *reinterpret_cast<const uint32 *>( &data[i*w] );
        prev &= ~m;
        val |= prev;
        *reinterpret_cast<uint32 *>( &data[i*w] ) = val;
    }
    std::vector<char> data;
};

TEST(int_block_test) {

    int_block ib;
    for (uint32 i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        ib.set(i, i+25);

    for (uint32 i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        CHECK_EQUAL(i+25, ib.get(i));
}
```

You'd be able to break this by giving it bad values, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. :))

Quite honestly, I think you'd be happier off representing them as 32-bit integers and just writing conversion functions.  But I suspect you don't have control over that.